# Не виден левый край при уменьшении ширины блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, позиционирование

Разметка html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Task 2.9</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        
        <div class="content">
            
            <div class="image">
                <img src="image.jpg">
            </div>
            
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse mollis libero lacinia, dictum nulla quis, lobortis turpis. Quisque auctor porta convallis. Proin vulputate placerat lectus et imperdiet. Donec pulvinar tempor posuere. Fusce nibh dolor, ornare vel egestas in, condimentum vel mi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam ac eleifend dui. Praesent malesuada sagittis odio vitae gravida. Donec sodales diam turpis, sed blandit ante bibendum sed. Vestibulum feugiat lectus a felis porttitor, id cursus purus ultricies. Nulla molestie pulvinar ipsum, eget fermentum urna ullamcorper non. In lacinia nisi at elit efficitur, ut congue nulla tempus. Donec et urna varius, efficitur felis at, blandit elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin quis convallis nibh, eget interdum turpis. Maecenas malesuada erat dictum felis ornare, id egestas augue mattis. Vivamus neque sapien, blandit nec accumsan in, lobortis faucibus quam. Cras porttitor, felis id consequat rhoncus, ipsum nunc pellentesque elit, quis rhoncus tortor ipsum blandit enim. Etiam ullamcorper turpis sit amet lectus bibendum, vel maximus ante bibendum. Pellentesque aliquet nisl ut dignissim malesuada. Morbi ac posuere nunc. Donec vitae pellentesque lectus. Sed sit amet purus pellentesque, maximus lorem nec, egestas massa. Fusce tempus sem non nunc finibus, ultrices sollicitudin mi porttitor. Ut sed justo nisl. Sed vel metus urna. Suspendisse semper diam vel pharetra hendrerit. Nulla ut justo elit. Aliquam pellentesque varius venenatis. Proin eu diam sed magna congue vehicula. Praesent eu enim ut ante vulputate posuere in quis enim. Integer ultrices augue rhoncus turpis pulvinar posuere.
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS стили:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.content {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 600px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.image {
    float: right;
}
```

Изучаю по чуть чуть верстку, и возник такой вопрос. При такой разметке и таких стилях добиваюсь того, чего хочу, а именно мне нужно чтобы блок с контентом содержал текст и изображение справа. Этот блок должен быть по центру. При уменьшении экрана по ширине, блок с контентом не должен сужаться вниз, а должен появиться горизонтальный ползунок. Это происходит, но работает криво, а именно не виден до конца левый край, хотя ползунок максимально слева. Что нужно сделать?
[image: Полный экран]

[image: Уменьшенный экран]

Comment: смотрите, при уменьшении экрана делаете media запрос и уменьшаете размер блока .content вот таким образом: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/bGOmQpw

Comment: Попробуй сделать оверфлоу не на контейнер, а на боди

Comment: @DovgalDima а почему это происходит, если присутствуют свойства flex? Как можно их оставить и при этом решить проблему?

Comment: @Maneken нет, так тоже не работает

Comment: @MonkeyMutant спасибо за ответ, но хотелось бы знать почему это происходит и не использовать медиа запрос

Answer (score 0):

Исправил ваш код под задачу, теперь полоса прокрутки работает и виден весь текст. Для этого убрал из контейнера flexbox свойства.

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10px;
}

.image {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">

    <div class="content">

        <div class="image">
            <img src="http://surl.li/lvasl">
        </div>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse mollis libero lacinia, dictum nulla
            quis, lobortis turpis. Quisque auctor porta convallis. Proin vulputate placerat lectus et imperdiet.
            Donec pulvinar tempor posuere. Fusce nibh dolor, ornare vel egestas in, condimentum vel mi. Cum sociis
            natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam ac eleifend dui.
            Praesent malesuada sagittis odio vitae gravida. Donec sodales diam turpis, sed blandit ante bibendum
            sed. Vestibulum feugiat lectus a felis porttitor, id cursus purus ultricies. Nulla molestie pulvinar
            ipsum, eget fermentum urna ullamcorper non. In lacinia nisi at elit efficitur, ut congue nulla tempus.
            Donec et urna varius, efficitur felis at, blandit elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
            et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin quis convallis nibh, eget interdum turpis. Maecenas
            malesuada erat dictum felis ornare, id egestas augue mattis. Vivamus neque sapien, blandit nec accumsan
            in, lobortis faucibus quam. Cras porttitor, felis id consequat rhoncus, ipsum nunc pellentesque elit,
            quis rhoncus tortor ipsum blandit enim. Etiam ullamcorper turpis sit amet lectus bibendum, vel maximus
            ante bibendum. Pellentesque aliquet nisl ut dignissim malesuada. Morbi ac posuere nunc. Donec vitae
            pellentesque lectus. Sed sit amet purus pellentesque, maximus lorem nec, egestas massa. Fusce tempus sem
            non nunc finibus, ultrices sollicitudin mi porttitor. Ut sed justo nisl. Sed vel metus urna. Suspendisse
            semper diam vel pharetra hendrerit. Nulla ut justo elit. Aliquam pellentesque varius venenatis. Proin eu
            diam sed magna congue vehicula. Praesent eu enim ut ante vulputate posuere in quis enim. Integer
            ultrices augue rhoncus turpis pulvinar posuere.
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
```